# I'm creating a karaoke-like app in android studio

Tags: android, audio-player, android-music-player

I'm creating a music player for my school project and I decided to add a game.. which is like a karaoke. I just want to ask, how can I time the lyrics with the song?

Comment: its is pretty much like the external subtitles work. check it out.

Comment: can you give me ideas to make it? I'm just newbie in android development @gvlachakis

Comment: This isn't a site for general advice like that. StackOverflow is for answering specific problems when you have already written code. You need to do some research on your own, try to build something, and then you can get help here with problems. Try finding a tutorial for karaoke or adding subtitles to a movie (they are basically the same thing) on android. (Tip: if you are only pulling up directions for how to turn captions on as a regular user, add the word developer or development to your search)

Comment: that's exactly what I need. Thank You! @drawinfinity :-)